# LAG window function in Redshift - show previous year and current year values in single row

Tags: amazon-redshift, analytics

I need to show previous year and current year values in a single row for a set of column combination. The scenario is given below:
I have a dataset like this:

```
Student City    Country Year Month Subject Marks
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Maths   90
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Maths   95
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Maths   95
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Maths   83
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Arts    90
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Arts    95
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Arts    95
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Arts    83
```

I want the output as:

```
Student  City  Country  Year  Month  Maths_curr  Maths_prev  Arts_curr Arts_prev  
John     Boston USA     2019  01     95          90          95        90
John     Boston USA     2018  01     90          null        90        null
Mark     London UK      2019  01     83          95          83        95
Mark     London UK      2018  01     95          null        95        null
```

I think, I need to use the LAG function to get this... I used this code

```
select student,city,country,year,month,subject,marks as curr,
lag(marks,1)over(partition by student,city,country,subject order by year,month) as prev
from <table>
order by student,city,country,year,month
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Student City    Countr  Year Month Subject  Curr  Prev
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Maths    95    90
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Maths    90    null
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Arts     95    90
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Arts     90    null
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Maths    83    95
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Maths    95    null
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Arts     83    95
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Arts     95    null
```

Can you help me in getting the desired output... Are LEAD or LAG, the correct functions to use in this scenario? Is there any other way to achieve this in Redshift?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried this code as well..

```
select student,city,country,year,month,subject,
case when substring(curr,1,1) = 'M' then cast(split_part(curr,' ',2) as integer) end as maths_curr,
case when substring(prev,1,1) = 'M' then cast(split_part(prev,' ',2) as integer) end as maths_prev,
case when substring(curr,1,1) = 'A' then cast(split_part(curr,' ',2) as integer) end as arts_curr,
case when substring(prev,1,1) = 'A' then cast(split_part(prev,' ',2) as integer) end as arts_prev
from
(select student,city,country,year,month,subject,
case when subject = 'MATHS' then 'M ' + cast(nvl(marks,0) as varchar)
     else 'A ' + cast(nvl(marks,0) as varchar)
     end as curr,
case when subject = 'MATHS' then 'M ' + cast(nvl(lag(marks,1)over (partition by student,city,country,subject order by year,mth),0) as varchar)
     else 'A ' + cast(nvl(lag(marks,1)over (partition by student,city,country,subject order by year,mth),0) as varchar)
     end as prev
from <table>
order by student,city,country,year,month)
```

In this I am getting output as:

```
Student City    Country Year Month Subject  Maths_Curr  Maths_Prev   Arts_Curr   Arts_Prev
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Maths    95          90           null        null
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Maths    90          null         null        null
John    Boston  USA    2019  01    Arts     null        null         95          90
John    Boston  USA    2018  01    Arts     null        null         90          null
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Maths    83          95           null        null
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Maths    95          null         null        null
Mark    London  UK     2019  01    Arts     null        null         83          95
Mark    London  UK     2018  01    Arts     null        null         95          null
```

Not sure where exactly I am going wrong.. Need some guidance here....

Comment: With the last code, I am getting the columns in a single row, but need to have the marks of all subjects for an year, in the same line, instead of having nulls and breaking the output into multiple rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH base AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN "Subject" = 'Maths' THEN "Marks" ELSE NULL END AS maths_current,
         CASE WHEN "Subject" = 'Arts' THEN "Marks" ELSE NULL END AS arts_current,
         CASE WHEN "Subject" = 'Maths' THEN LAG("Marks") OVER (PARTITION BY "Student","City","Country","Subject" ORDER BY "Year","Month") ELSE NULL END AS previous_math,
         CASE WHEN "Subject" = 'Arts' THEN LAG("Marks") OVER (PARTITION BY "Student","City","Country","Subject" ORDER BY "Year","Month") ELSE NULL END AS previous_arts
  FROM <table>
)

SELECT "Student",
       "City",
       "Country",
       "Year",
       "Month",
       MAX(maths_current) AS Maths_curr,
       MAX(previous_math) AS Maths_prev,
       MAX(arts_current) AS Arts_curr,
       MAX(previous_arts) AS Arts_prev
FROM base
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4 DESC,5 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Vitor.... It worked... I did try the group by function, but was not sure of which aggregate function to use after that. The max() didn't strike me...